# Combine two distinct dataframes to show all possible iterations

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm looking to combine dataframes df1 and df2 to get df3 in Python, most preferably in a one-liner (*that is, no "for all x in df1.LETS..."*).

I'm at a current loss for words to use with my Google-fu, so here I am at StackExchange, hoping another programmer can help fill in my mental blank with this predicament.

Thank you!

```
df1    df2      df3
LETS   NUMS     LETS  NUMS
 A      1        A     1
 B      2        A     2
        3        A     3
        4        A     4
                 B     1
                 B     2
                 B     3
                 B     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1.LETS, df2.NUMS],
                          names=("LETS", "NUMS"))).reset_index()
#   LETS  NUMS
#0    A     1
#1    A     2
#2    A     3
#3    A     4
#4    B     1
#5    B     2
#6    B     3
#7    B     4
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'LETS':list('AB')})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'NUMS':range(1,5)})
```

`cross join` solution with [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) + [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) column with `constant` and [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) helper column `A`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1.assign(A=1), df2.assign(A=1), on='A').drop('A', axis=1)
print (df)
  LETS  NUMS
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    A     3
3    A     4
4    B     1
5    B     2
6    B     3
7    B     4
```

Another solution with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and new function in pandas `0.20.1` - [`MultiIndex.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.to_frame.html)

```
df = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df1['LETS'], df2['NUMS']]).to_frame()
df.columns = ['LETS','NUMS']
print (df)
    LETS  NUMS
A 1    A     1
  2    A     2
  3    A     3
  4    A     4
B 1    B     1
  2    B     2
  3    B     3
  4    B     4

print (df.reset_index(drop=True))
  LETS  NUMS
0    A     1
1    A     2
2    A     3
3    A     4
4    B     1
5    B     2
6    B     3
7    B     4
```